# Browser event does not bubble

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling

I want to make the drag drop to the element,and I dot not want the parent of this element capture the click or drag event, so I use the bubble model, however the element which I want to drag contain a child who own the same size (width, height, left...) of this element.

For example:

```
<div id="div_con" style="left: 20px; top: 50px; width: 181px; height: 357px; position: absolute; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer;" class="drag">
    <img src="test.PNG" id="Over_Label_1912694_Img" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 181px; height: 357px; position: relative;">
</div>
```

`div#div_con` is the element I want to drag, but since the `div#div_con` and the img have the same size, so user can never click the `div#div_con`. Since the img is above it.

So I bind the `mouseDown`, `mouseMove`, `mouseUp` events to the whole document:

```
document.onmousedown = OnMouseDown;
document.onmouseup = OnMouseUp;
```

In my opinion,when user click the img under the `div#div_con`, the `mouseDown` event will bubble to `div#div_con`.

Since I just want to drag the `div#div_con`,so I make a check in the `mouseDown` handler:

```
if ((e.button == 1 && window.event != null || e.button == 0) && target.className == 'drag')
{  //do the start the move}
```

But it does not work.

This is the complete example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5SCwG/

Comment: what about a mask over the element that serves as a "drag handle" over the entire element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it is bubbling. That's why document is receiving the event to begin with. The problem you're experiencing is that event.target refers to the object clicked, and event.currentTarget refers to the object listening and neither one of those are your div.

You will either need to use an event listener on the div directly, or you'll need to get `target.parentElement` and then use that as _dragElement.

[Check it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/5SCwG/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the image as `background-image` of the `DIV` and remove the `IMG` drag & drop works: http://jsfiddle.net/HxaJ4/